User should see option to select only a single date rather than a range of date in Google Looker studio
In Google looker studio, I can add a date range control that is automatically applied to all the tables in the dashboard.

I can then select a single date, by selecting the same date in start and end date option.
In my usecase this is ugly, as the user will only be selecting a single date at a time. How do i show the user only a single date to select in a calendar.


I would love to see this option. I'm not sure if there is a more accessible solve (hope there is). For now, I have dropdowns for month, day and year (as compared to a single dropdown (which can be a pain to look for the correct date), to isolate a single date input selection and still maintain accessibility.
